# Python, изменение кодировки при архивации

Tags: python, python-2.x

При архивирование файлов этим нехитрым скриптом, все файлы, что имеют в название кириллицу, меняют кодировку и становятся нечитабельные.

```
import tarfile
import os
import datetime

DATE = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

# filename for tar archive bak-
output_filename = r"C:\py\to_backup\bak-" + DATE + ".tar.gz"
# directory with file for backup
source_dir = r"C:\py\from_backup"
# path for backup
bak_dir = r"C:\py\to_backup"


def make_tarfile(output_filename, source_dir):
    tar = tarfile.open(output_filename, "w:gz")
    tar.add(source_dir, arcname=os.path.basename(source_dir));
    tar.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, нужно было добавить параметр encoding,

```
archive_encoding = 'cp1251'
tar = tarfile.open(output_filename, "w:gz", encoding=archive_encoding)
```